# Django PatchOauth2 request.POST get none

Tags: python, django, oauth, request

i write a api in django:

```
class TagDomain(PatchOauth2, APIView):
    def post(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
            records = request.POST['data']
            for record in records:
               pass
```

in local,i write a tagdomain.py:

```
def tagdomain():
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    url= "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/domain/tag_domain/"
    par={'data':data}
    r = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(par), headers=headers, auth=('name', 'passwd'))
    ....
```

when i run tagdomain.py,request.POST is null,how can i get the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in django: records = request.DATA, it can get the data